# How to do a balance-test in a randomized controlled experiment?

Tags: random-allocation

Can someone explain to me how I do a balance test in a randomized controlled experiment? 
Do I choose the important covariates and estimate whether there is a significant difference between my two treatment groups and my control group regarding the chosen covariates?